# Flutter : Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom > Resetting to invalid mark

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The app is working fine in debug mode, but I tried to build the final apk I got this error, below the stacktrace

```
 > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
 > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
   > Resetting to invalid mark
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to gradle being unable to find the dependency.

If you don't need this testing dependency, you can just remove it from the `android/app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: The matter is that, this dependency is not in the `build.gradle` file. I tried so many option. At this end I found like the problem what coming from the android folder, so I removed the android folder, and I took another project android folder to replace it and change package name, and clean every with `flutter clean` and rebuild the app again and it worked fine